# Time with meridiem indicator and periods is unacceptable to Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am using /copy command to copy data from a file to a table in Postgres, but it raise error time zone "p.m." not recognized.

Running a simple Insert query also raise the same error

```
insert into incoming_data_redgold_facts_dictionaries (facts_date_added )values('29/12/2015 3:23:43 P.M.')
```

How to modify Postgres so it can accept given time format?

Answer (score 0):

The "best" (=portable) way is to use an ANSI timestamp literal:

```
insert into incoming_data_redgold_facts_dictionaries 
  (facts_date_added )
values
  (timestamp '2015-12-29 15:23:43');
```

Postgres also accepts strings formatted as ISO timestamps directly without the need for the `timestamp` keyword (as the SQL standard does)

```
insert into incoming_data_redgold_facts_dictionaries 
  (facts_date_added )
values
  ('2015-12-29 15:23:43');
```

If you do want to keep that format, use the `to_timestamp()` function:

```
insert into incoming_data_redgold_facts_dictionaries 
  (facts_date_added )
values
  (to_timestamp('29/12/2015 3:23:43 P.M.', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss P.M.'));
```

More details in the manual:

- [Date/Time literals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT)
- [Data type formatting functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE)

Comment: @Gull: `copy` only accepts ISO formatted timestamps if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in columns that do not conform to the PG format, you basically have two options:

1. Parse the input file before `\copy` to make the data conformant. How you do this depends on your file and available tools.
2. Load the data into a table with a column type that will accept your data and then `ALTER COLUMN` with an appropriate conversion function.

In PG, the second option would work fairly easily in this scenario. The `facts_date_added` column should be of type `varchar` or `text` before the `\copy`. Once the data is imported into the table you can alter the column type using an appropriate conversion function for the data:

```
ALTER TABLE incoming_data_redgold_facts_dictionaries
  ALTER COLUMN facts_date_added
  SET DATA TYPE timestamp USING to_timestamp(facts_date_added, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS P.M.');
```